# ScriptManager's AXD resources not found because of UrlRewrite

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using `UrlRewrite` to remove the `.aspx` from files.
The rule I am using:

```
<rule name="RewriteASPX">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
</rule>
```

In one of my web forms I use a `ScriptManager`.
When the page loads, some `.axd` files are being linked too, for example:

`WebResource.axd?d=LONG_STRING`

But, it tells me that the above file was not found, and the requested URL was:  `/WebResource.axd.aspx`

I thought the conditions in my rule are supposed to filter a case like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this one.

I changed the rule this way:

```
<match url="^[^.]+$" />
```

And now it doesn't apply the rule to files as the one I mentioned, and only to extension-less files.